# I want to move the values(php array) to js array

Tags: javascript, php

> This part is recieving $_POST array and creating php array

```
<body>
<div class="bg-img">
<?php
$post_count=count($_POST);
$loop_count=$post_count/4;
$name=array();
$quantity=array();
$price=array();
$cost=array();

for($i=0;$i<$loop_count;$i++)
{
  if($i==0)
  {
    $name[]=$_POST['name'];
    $quantity[]=$_POST['quantity'];
    $price[]=$_POST['price'];
    $cost[]=$_POST['cost'];
  }
  else
  {
    $name[]=$_POST['name'.(string)$i];
    $quantity[]=$_POST['quantity'.(string)$i];
    $price[]=$_POST['price'.(string)$i];
    $cost[]=$_POST['cost'.(string)$i];

  }
}
```

> This part is moving the values from php array to js array

```
  let loop_count= Number(<?= $loop_count; ?>);
  let name=new Array();
  let quantity=new Array() ;
  let price=new Array() ;
  let cost=new Array ();
  let test;

  for (let i = 0; i<loop_count; i++)
  {
      *name.push(<?= array_shift($name) ?>);
      quantity.push(<?= array_shift($quantity)?>);
      price.push(<?= array_shift($price)?> );
      cost.push(<?= array_shift($cost)?> );*

  }
```

However array_shift isn't worked well. name(include  quantity,price,cost) array's values is same.

$name(include case quantity,price ,cost)'s first value isn't deleted.

What's problem??  the Result of trying about array_pop is same. Last value isn't deleted.

Comment: I  think there might be some confusion about how PHP and Javascript run & when. PHP runs BEFORE any content is sent to the browser and Javascript runs when the page has loaded. Your Javascript code has a loop and you hope to get different values in that loop ( I presume ) because you call the PHP function `array_shift`.... if that is the case sorry - it does not work that way

Answer (score 0):

As @Professor Abronsius says you are mixing up times of execution on server and browser sides. But even in your case it's possible to resolve your task in a simplier way. Using [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function your second code sample can be rewritten in the followin way:

```php
let name = <?= json_encode($name) ?>;
let quantity = <?= json_encode($quantity) ?>;
let price = <?= json_encode($price) ?>;
let cost = <?= json_encode($cost) ?>;
```

Comment: Probably more effective to create one associative array in php rather than 4 separate arrays

Comment: @charlietfl totally agree with you, but we don't know purpose of these variables.

Comment: Thank you everyone I will test your advice.